# Is Distributed transaction still not support is efcore and .Net6

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, distributed-transactions

Dears,

I am going to use multiple databases in my application but as you know, distributed transactions is not supported in efcore yet.

**So is there any work around to save multiple transactions across multiple databases in efcore or .Net6 or when will it be supported ?**

Comment: Based on the [plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/plan#distributed-transactions) and linked issue it seems that it can be included in .NET 7 release with Windows-only support.